# Having some trouble with my questionnaire database

Tags: sql-server

I  am having a bit of trouble with some tables for my questionnaire app.

The deal is that some questions have just **one** follow up question, some have **multiple** follow up questions where the order in they are asked do not matter and some have **no** follow up question (mostly the ones at the end of each question chain).

*My first idea:*

Question (*ID*, question)

Next(*mainQuestion, nextQuestion*)

Here there **have to** be follow up questions because "nextQuestion" can't be null

*My second idea:*

[image]

The problem here it that there can only be one follow up question.

The only solution I see is to add an ID to the Next table in my first idea, so that the "nextQuestion" and "mainQuestion" are no longer part of the PK. The ID would never be used so thats why I am here. Do you guys have a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you have an additional entity that you are not modeling, something like "QuestionSet".  A questionnaire consists of a sequence of QuestionSets.  Most of these consist of individual questions.  Some are sets that can be asked in any order.  With this in mind, you should be able to express the questionnaires.

Answer (score 1):

I think rather then having a separate table for next questions you should have something like this

```
Table_Question

QuestionID text        FollowedBy
 1         Some Text   NULL
 2         Some Text   1
 3         Some Text   2
 4         Some Text   3
 5         Some Text   4
 6         Some Text   2
 7         Some Text   6
```

and so on...... this will work just fine if you have a follow up question only followed by one main question.

In case of having a follow up question followed up by multiple main questions then you will need a separate table for follow up question, something like this

```
Table_Question
QuestionID text        
 1         Some Text  
 2         Some Text 
 3         Some Text
 4         Some Text 

Table_FollowUpQuestion
FolUpQuestionID Text       QuestionID 
1                Some Text    1
2                Some Text    1
3                Some Text    2
4                Some Text    3
5                Some Text    4
```

And so on .....

And and even better or I would best option for you will be to have 3 tables

> 1 MainQuestions 
>   2 Sub_Question
>   3 Followed_Question

Something like this

```
Table_Question
QuestionID text        
 1         Some Text  
 2         Some Text 
 3         Some Text
 4         Some Text 

Table_Sub_Question
FolUpQuestionID Text       
1                Some Text 
2                Some Text 
3                Some Text
4                Some Text
5                Some Text

Table_FollowUpQuestion
FolUpQuestionID    QuestionID 
1                    2
2                    3
3                    3
4                    4
5                    5
```

Comment: This is like my second idea...
The problem here is that I want to have more than one follow up question, but because QuestionID has to be unique it can only have one follow up

Comment: @David thats not an issue like in my given example question 3 and 6 are follow up questions of question 2.

Comment: I need to have something like Q1 has follow up questions Q1, Q2 and Q3.

Comment: @David see my update, you will need another table to have all the follow up questions with their main questionID referencing to the QuestionID in main Questions Table.

Comment: Thank you. Ive found my own mistake by reading your answer :D

Comment: @David what you are suggesting will do the job for now but I think if you do it the way I have suggested as third Option in my answer it will make your queries a lot simpler and a bit less messy database design :)

Answer (score 0):

Question (ID, question)

Next(mainQuestion, nextQuestion)

Still is the best solution.

If I don't want an question to have a follow up question than I dont have to set "nextQuestion" to NULL, but I just stop adding rows to the table.

Answer (score 0):

- If one question could have zero, one or more questions but one question could be preceded by zero or one question then `Question` table should have a FK pointing to previous question ID: `dbo.Question(QuestionID, Content, PreviousQuestionID)`
- If one question could have zero, one or more questions but one question could be preceded by zero, one or more questions then you need another table `dbo.AsocQuestions`:

`dbo.Question(QuestionID, Content)` (PK = `QuestionID`)

`dbo.AsocQuestions(FromQuestionID, ToQuestionID)` (PK = `FromQuestionID` + `ToQuestionID`)